# EF Core multiple OneToMany relations

Tags: c#, database-design, entity-framework-core

I'm creating my database in SQL Server and it's mapping. I would like to allow multiple tables (for example `Purchase` and `Provider`) to have entries in the table `Documents`:

```
public class Document
{        
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    public string? Note { get; set; }
}

public class Provider
{        
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class Purchase
{        
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

I created the mappings for the two classes:

```
public class ProviderMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Provider>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Provider> builder)
    {
        builder
            .HasKey(e => e.Id);

        builder
            .Property(e => e.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        builder
            .HasMany(x => x.Documents)
            .WithOne()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.OwnerId);
}

public class PurchaseMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Purchase>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Purchase> builder)
    {
        builder
             .HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder                
            .HasMany(x => x.Documents)
            .WithOne()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.OwnerId);
    }
}
```

But the SQL Server database doesn't let me create a foreign key on the same column.

Is there a method how to make this possible? I had this before when creating database tables manually if I call correct (was a few years ago), but can't get it running with Entity Framework Core.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix document by adding purcharse Id

```
public class Document
{        
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string? Note { get; set; }

    public Guid ProviderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Provider Provider { get; set; }

    public Guid PurchaseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Purchase Purchase { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well this would be the last option I can imagine to use. I dont want to add a colum for every entity that can have documents. Isnt there an option how to map that. I would even be ok if I cannot do it with a foreign key.Is the limit here EntityFramework or the nature of foreign key?

Comment: @garcipat  As alternative you have to remove   public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; } from Purchase. You can not keep the list of  table records as a column of the table. Or you can add a special table  to keep the relations between purchase and document.